# Socket.io dynamic rooms

Tags: socket.io

I am writing an app which creates many dynamic rooms, they should live as long as someone is connected. if all clients disconnect they should be cleared

does socket.io clear such rooms automatically? or do I need to clear them manually somehow?

Comment: ok, it does!  Manager.prototype.onLeave = function (id, room) {
  if (this.rooms[room]) {
    var index = this.rooms[room].indexOf(id);

    if (index >= 0) {
      this.rooms[room].splice(index, 1);
    }

    if (!this.rooms[room].length) {
      delete this.rooms[room];
    }
    delete this.roomClients[id][room];
  }
};

Answer (score 7):

Yes `socket.io` does clean up rooms when the client is disconnected.

Read more at [the git page](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms)